# Foreign key in a different object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two classes:

```
public class Equipment
{
    public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EquipmentTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class EquipmentType
{
    public int EquipmentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm returning list of Equipment from database as a `List<Equipment>`.

Then I bind it to the Gridview through `Gridview1.DataSource = equipmentList`
That works fine, but what I need to do is I need to display EquipmentType Name instead of ID. And, in edit mode I need to display Dropdown list with all available EQuipmentTypeNames. Any suggestion on how to do that? what is the architecture?

Comment: What is your data access layer? Entity Framework, Linq-to-SQL, nHibernate, home-grown SQL statements, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying in the GridView you have a couple of options, ranging from easiest to hardest.

1. Use a nested SqlDataSource for equipment type, and display in a disabled dropdownlist.
2. Load the equipment type with the equipment for data binding.
3. Programmatically load equipment type in the RowDataBound event.

Here is an example of how you could include the equipment type data:

```
var equips = GetEquipment();
var equipTypes = GetEquipmentTypes();

var data = from eq in equips
            join et in equipTypes on eq.EquipmentTypeId equals et.EquipmentTypeId
            select new { eq.EquipmentId, eq.Name, et.TypeName };

GridView.DataSource = data;
```

For editing in the GridView, it  is simplest  just to use a DropDownList with it's own  SqlDataSource (or custom data source), which is bound to `Equipment.EquipmentTypeId`, something like this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="EquipmentTypeDropDown" runat="server"
        SelectedValue='<%#Bind("EquipmentTypeId") %>'
        DataSource='<%#GetEquipmentTypes() %>'
        DataTextField="TypeName" DataValueField="EquipmentTypeId">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Where `GetEquipmentTypes()` is just a method that returns `List<EquipmentType>` that I'm using for databinding.  In this case, since I don't have a database, I'm just generating data in a stub object.  You would replace this method with your BAL class that reads the data from the database (or ADO.Net code, or an ObjectDataSource, etc.).

```
protected List<EquipmentType> GetEquipmentTypes()
{
    return new List<EquipmentType> {
        new EquipmentType { EquipmentTypeId = 1, TypeName = "Baseball" },
        new EquipmentType { EquipmentTypeId = 2, TypeName = "Football" },
        new EquipmentType { EquipmentTypeId = 3, TypeName = "Soccer" },
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! great! Can you please provide me with an example of Binding dropdown without sqldatasource (in the code-behind). I do not quite understand this line: DataSource='<%#GetEquipmentTypes() %>'

Comment: `GetEquipmentTypes()` is a method I wrote to load equipment types data from the database.  I have added my sample method above.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend extending your `Equipment` class out with a child class (let's call it `EquipmentEx` for now), and add on the `EquipmentTypeName` property. Instead of your stored proc returning just the `Equipment` columns, join in the `EquipmentType` table, and include the additional type name column.

Or create a view that does the join, and have your stored proc return the view contents instead of the  table contents - it depends on how your app is generally organized.

Once you have an `EquipmentEx` object, then you've got your answer for displaying the type name instead of ID - it's already part of the object, so you can display it just like normal.

As far as putting the dropdown into the GridView, you'll probably be working with the EditItemTemplate tag inside your template field, but I really haven't worked enough with the GridView to know exactly what it will look like. I've always preferred to handle this kind of thing a little more manually, rather than trusting ASP.NET to do it for me. But since your dropdownlist's value will represent the EquipmentTypeID, you should be able to bind this value to the object when you save it, instead of a TextBox value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is the purpose of creating a child class? Why Can't I just add an EqupmentTypeName directly into Equipment class?

Comment: I'm assuming your `Equipment` class represents a specific table in your database. If this is what you're doing, then I generally would avoid adding properties to your data classes that don't exist on the table itself, so extending the class (or creating a brand new class that's similar to the old one) would avoid this problem. But if your classes aren't 1-to-1 with your database, then you're probably ok to just modify your original class. It just depends on how your data access layer is organized.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , if you want to bind it like that you need to make your own class that contains all informations , like that:

```
public class CompositeEquipment
{
    public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

And if you are using sql statements or stored procedures you can write the following :

```
SELECT Equipment.EquipmentID,Equipment.Name,EquipmentType.TypeName FROM Equipment
INNER JOIN  EquipmentType ON Equipment.EquipmentTypeId = EquipmentType.EquipmentTypeId
```

and when reading SqlDataReader do the following :

```
List<Equipment> lstEquipment = new List<Equipment>();
while(reader.read())
{
Equipment eq = new Equipment();
eq.reader["EquipmentId"];
eq.reader["Name"];
eq.reader["TypeName "];
lstEquipment.Add(eq);
}
Gridview1.DataSource = lstEquipment;
```

and if you are using EntityFramework as Data Access Layer you can write the following :

```
using(YourOwnContext context = new YourOwnContext)
{
List<Equipment> lstEquipment = (from e in context.Equipments
                               select new Equipment
                               {
                                  EquipmentId = e.EquipmentId,
                                  Name = e.Name,
                                  TypeName = e.EquipmentType.TypeName
                               }}).ToList();
Gridview1.DataSource = lstEquipment;
```

Hope this helps you.